# Pickling without Sterilization - Is It Safe?

Tags: pickling

Is this [recipe](http://www.foodbuzz.com/recipes/4066488-spicy-dill-pickles) safe? The author is making pickles without sterilizing the jars first and I've ALWAYS read that you have to sterilize the jars first.

Comment: There's a difference between canning safety for long-term room temperature storage and safety for refrigerator storage. This recipe says to store in the fridge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recipe appears to be close to a standard Summer Pickle recipe.
It's about a 9% brine with 3.75% acetic acid, which should effectively discourage human pathogens.
It is not a fermented product.
They're meant to be refrigerated for at most a few months, not stored on some dusty basement shelf.
Refrigerated properly, I'd eat them without concern.

Comment: Ah, so the length of time is the concern.

Comment: @Robert: Length of time is always a concern but no, the real concern here is refrigeration, not time. High-acid foods last pretty much forever in the fridge, because both acid and refrigeration are hostile to most bacteria and together they eliminate almost any risk; if you don't refrigerate then the risk goes up considerably.